# WebExtension: Bypass permission denied to access property "target"

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

Using FF WebExtension, I am trying to clone an element from a website that I don't own. This is what I use(taken from [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)).

```
// Get the last <li> element ("Milk") of <ul> with id="myList2"
var itm = document.getElementById("myList2").lastChild;

// Copy the <li> element and its child nodes
var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);

// Append the cloned <li> element to <ul> with id="myList1"
document.getElementById("myList1").appendChild(cln);
```

However, this error appears:

> Error: Permission denied to access property "target"

Here is my manifest:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "w",
  "version": "0.1",

  "description": "w",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost/*"],
      "js": ["rh-addbutton.js","rh-addpage.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["http://localhost/*"]

}
```

Am I missing a permission? I can't find the right permission on MDN.